# Windows AdMediatorControl not displaying test ad

Tags: windows-phone-8, ads

I'm setting Microsoft Advertising through Ad Mediator.
I did all required setups* but the ad doesn't appear on emulator.
It is set up to:

```
Application ID: test_client
Ad Unit ID: Image480_80
```

I'm building it for Windows Phone 8.

*added Connected Service, set up Microsoft Advertising there, checked capabilities, put AdMediatorControl into drawing surface

Does anyone encountered such problem?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem. Maybe it'll be interesting for someone else.

Ad Mediator stops working if there are other advertising plugins even if they are not used in game.
In my case it were prime31 ads.